# download a big file and avoid data corruption

Tags: download, download-manager

Today I was downloading a 1GB file using IDM software and since the network was unstable, for many times after downloading much MBs of the file it was saying that because of data corruption it will start downloading again.

How can I avoid this problem whether with this software or others? I mean after downloading an amount of the file how I can be sure that downloaded parts have no problem.

Comment: Basically a Torrent ^

Comment: I have direct link to the file not a torrent

Comment: ftp can resume a download. So you could start downloading it, abort after 256MB, restart FTP and resume with the next part.

Comment: Also, why would getting it in parts prevent data corruption?

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would stick to a download manager like [DownThemAll](http://www.downthemall.net/) for FireFox.

I've used it in the past for a number of things, but in particular, downloading large 1gb+ files and have **NEVER** experienced any problems. Plus I find it actually downloads files quicker and you have the option to pause the downloads (without having to worry that the file might corrupt/lose download).

Answer (score 1):

There is an experimental tool available, this converts the download to a torrent. 
http://burnbit.com/

Warning: never used it personally. Registration may be required.